# How to keras deep-learning classify with csv data?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, classification

I have data that falls into two categories according to certain conditions.
(ex) condition1&condition2&condition3 = 1)

And I tried to make a model that classifies it with the code below.

```python
dataset_csv = np.loadtxt('dataset.csv', delimiter=',')   

x_train=dataset_csv[:round(len(dataset)*0.9),0:3]
y_train=dataset_csv[:round(len(dataset)*0.9),3]
x_test=dataset_csv[round(len(dataset)*0.9):,0:3]
y_test=dataset_csv[round(len(dataset)*0.9):,3]


model =Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs = 10, batch_size =24)

scores = model.evaluate(x_test,y_test)
```

However, the results of the prediction came out as follows.

```python
array([[9.414976e-08]], dtype=float32)
```

I thought that the y value I set was recognized as a class.

but it isn't.

Is there a way that set  y  to class value, and  return a class value if I put a condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you use a binary classification. Because you use one output neuron. model.predict will give you the likelyhood of how likely the sample belong to signal.

You can simply define a threshold to determine if the prediction correspnd to a signal prediction or not (most of the time it's 0.5). Something like this:

```
predict_output = np.array([0.52396882, 0.20368976, 0.06553409, 0.52519849, 0.20538633])
predicted_classes = (predict_output > 0.5).astype(int)

predicted_classes: array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

Here predict_output is an example for the output of model.predict if you call it with 5 samples. predicted_classes should then be your desired result.

Comment: i wonder < 'predicted_classes = array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0])' > is mean result of <'predicted_classes = (predict_output > 0.5).astype(int)'>?

Comment: Yes it's the result. I clarified the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. It helped me.